# Drawing on Transparent HDC while Mouse Move

Tags: c++, gdi+

Using C++ and GDI+, I am drawing a rectangle on top of a image and Moving/Resizing the rectangle along with my MouseMovements, It was causing lots of flickering , so I decided to create a a transprent HDC on top on my Control. At the time of click I create that HDC and Draw on that HDC.

Here is my code...

```
HDC mSourceHDC; // Handle to the display device context 
HDC mMemoryDC;
HBITMAP mBitmap;
HBITMAP mOverlayBitmap;
```

in my Mouse Click CallBack

```
mSourceHDC = GetDC(hWnd); // Hwnd is the HWND of my control

RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
int32 clientheight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
int32 clientWidth = rc.right - rc.left;

mMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mSourceHDC);
mBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mSourceHDC, clientWidth, clientheight);
mOverlayBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(mMemoryDC, mBitmap);

//SetBkMode(mMemoryDC,TRANSPARENT); // Line 1
```

// In my Mouse Move CallBack

```
if(mMemoryDC != NULL) {
  Gdiplus::Graphics gdiGraphics(mMemoryDC);
  gdiGraphics.Clear(Gdiplus::Color.LightGray);  // Line 2

  Gdiplus::Pen* myPen = new Gdiplus::Pen(Gdiplus::Color::White);
  myPen->SetWidth(2);

  Gdiplus::GraphicsPath *cropRectPath = new Gdiplus::GraphicsPath();
  cropRectPath->AddRectangle(cropRectF); // This cropRectF is my rectangle 
  gdiGraphics.DrawPath(myPen, cropRectPath); 

  BitBlt(mSourceHDC, 0, 0,  clntWdth, clntheight, mMemoryDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

// In Mouse Leave Callback

```
if(mMemoryDC != NULL) {
  SelectObject(mMemoryDC, mOverlayBitmap);
  DeleteObject(mBitmap);
  DeleteDC(mMemoryDC);

  ReleaseDC(hWnd, mSourceHDC);
}
```

However, My rectangle is drawing correctly but during MouseMovement, my whole Window Becomes Gray and the Image is not shown, If I remove Line 2, then whole area becomes Black , Even I tried

```
gdiGraphics.Clear(Gdiplus::Color.Transparent);  in Line 2, still it turns Black.
```

I wanted to become this memory HDC transparent so that my Image is shown during the Mouse Move.

Any Idea where I am going wrong.
Thanks

-Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying from the memory DC using `Bitblt` with `SRCCOPY`.  That's going to overwrite everything.  The `SetBkMode` call is just for drawing text with GDI--that's not relevant to blitting bitmaps.

The way to eliminate the flicker is to render *everything* to an offscreen bitmap, and then blit the final result back to the window DC.  That's called double-buffering.

Create the bitmap and the memory DC as before.  Instead of trying to clear the memory DC, copy whatever is supposed to appear in the client area to the memory DC.  Then draw the selection rectangle on top of that.  Finally, blit the memory DC back to the window DC (as you're already doing).

Comment: As you said, Instead of trying to clear the memory DC, copy whatever is supposed to appear in the client area to the memory DC.

So do you mean I should not do this..
gdiGraphics.Clear(Gdiplus::Color.LightGray);  // Line 2

and instead of this, In My case, I need to copy my background Image [using gdiGraphics.DrawImage(...)] and then my Rectangle to memory DC and my final BitBlt is correct.

Please let me know, If I get this one correct ?

Thanks..

Comment: Could anyone tell me how can I create transparent HDC in this case so that my original Image is visible. I dont want to copy my image into memory HDC since that will be an overkill..

Comment: @Pankaj: There is no such thing as a transparent device context in GDI.  You could try using GDI+ to make a 32-bpp bitmap with an alpha channel and then use AlphaBlend, but I'd recommend the simply approach I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Yes, @Adrian, After doing some research, I found your answer as the most appropriate one. I implemented that and It is working fine.
Many Thanks